# AWS CDK, Adding VPC and Tags to aws_ecs Cluster, how?

Tags: aws-cdk

In creating an ECS Cluster on AWS using the Python CDK, I want to add a VPC and Tags to that Cluster definition.

To use Tags, I need to use aws_ecs.CfnCluster instead of aws_ecs.Cluster.
But I can't find where to specify the VPC in the aws_Ecs.CfnCluster.

Or, to rephrase the problem:

To use a VPC, I need to use aws.ecs.Cluster instead of aws_ecs.CfnCluster.
But I can't find where to specify the Tags in the aws_ecs.Cluster

#### Resources

[aws_ecs.cfnCluster documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_ecs/CfnCluster.html#aws_cdk.aws_ecs.CfnCluster.ClusterSettingsProperty) : No VPC parameter

[aws_ecs.Cluster documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/python/aws_cdk.aws_ecs/Cluster.html) : No Tags parameter

Anybody having an idea how to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: You don't need to use `CfnCluster` to use tags. use `Tags.of(myCluster).add()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, found it. Thanks to @gshpychka.

Code looks like this:

```py
class ECSStack(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        # What is my vpc_id
        for arg in kwargs:
            if arg == "vpc":
                self.vpc = kwargs[arg]

        del kwargs['vpc']. # Otherwise super.__init__ gets stressed.
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)

        slug = self.node.try_get_context("slug")
        if slug is None:
            slug = "Unknown"

        taggroup = self.node.try_get_context("group")
        if taggroup is None:
            taggroup = f"{slug}"

        # The ECS Cluster
        ecs_cluster = aws_ecs.Cluster(
            scope=self,
            id=f'{slug}-ECS-Cluster',
            cluster_name=f'{slug}-ECS-Cluster',
            vpc=self.vpc,
        )
        Tags.of(ecs_cluster).add("Group", f'{taggroup}')
        Tags.of(ecs_cluster).add("Name", f'{slug}-ECSCLUSTER')
```

Comment: General tip: instead of that hacy-looking code in the beginning to get the `vpc` argument, just make it an explicit keywoard argument next to `scope` and `id`.